# Black screen freezing in Macbook EFI Boot

Tags: linux, macbook, efi, gnu, black-screen-of-death

I had Ubuntu on my external hard drive, I had to delete it because i ruined it, after that I reinstalled it and now when I try to boot into my SEAGATE ubuntu hard drive it stuck on a black screen.

I tried installing Manjaro, other linux too but it doesn't wanna work.

Before, when I tried to boot into `EFI Boot` in my Macbook, if there was no hard drive attached, it would used to show me GNU GRUB minimal bash editing, but after the case even GNU GRUB editing doesn't show up and it's the black screen again.

Also, the black screen is sudden, it freezes as soon as I click on EFI Boot. I dont think this is the problem of my installation technique.

```
Macbook Specs:
MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
Processor: 1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had any luck! I have a 2019 MacBook Pro, and can't boot from any bootable Linux EFI bootable USB. Tried Ubuntu and Fedora. Also tried booting from an external drive.

There's a startup security utility where you need to adjust some settings, see this link: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208198 Tried that, also didn't help.

Comment: Same here. Nothing is working on my MacBook Pro 2019, but it worked on my 2016.